# Finding period of pendulum through interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I’m looking for finding an efficient answer to this problem, which is to find the period time of a pendulum using interpolation.

The pendulum behavior was given using the equations
$\phi’’+\frac g L \sin(\phi)$,
$\phi(0)=\frac{6\pi}{7}$, $\phi’(0)=0.8$,$0\leq t \leq T$
I’ve rewritten this to a system of first order differential equations and solved it using Runge-Kutta 4.

You can find an image of the plotted solution below, where the blue graph shows the pendulum movement:
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2sM8.png)

I want to find an interpolation over a subset of the two periods I’ve plotted to find the period time, but I’m a little stuck trying to pick what to do. Particularly which points I’m supposed to interpolate over and also what degree of polynomial I should pick. I’ve heard that you could get away with a low (1st, 2nd) degree polynomial, but I really can not figure out how.

Comment: From the wording of the question I cannot well understand what data is known. Is it experimental data ? Is it computed data from Runge-Kutta 4 solving of the ODE ? If it is computed data you simply have to pick the data each time the angle crosses zero.

Comment: It is computed data from Runge-Kutta 4, sorry if it was not clear. I’m still trying to wrap my head around how to interpolate efficiently to find where the angle crosses zero.

Comment: How the data is readable? On what format ? Can the data be download ?

Comment: One cannot reproduce your calculus and curve if the values of g ad L are not given.

Comment: What point does the interpolation refer to? Solving the free boundary condition from the function table produced via RK4? Using the derivatives vectors from the RK4 stages for 5th degree Hermite interpolation? Taking numerical solutions for several step sizes and then using Richardson *extra*polation? If possible, provide an overview of the algorithm as you understand it with general step descriptions.

Comment: Using another software I solved the ODE with incremental time method. There is no difficulty to catch the time each time the angle changes of sign. The difference between two successive catches gives the half_period. The accuracy can be as good as one want with low incremental time. No need for interpolation to have an even better accuracy than with interpolation. This method is valid for computed data not for scattered experimental data. Very simple to implement in the software just adding a few lines of code

Comment: You may be interested by the formulas in this section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum#Period_of_oscillation

Comment: Theoretical formulas to compute the amplitude and the period are added to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to compute the zero crossings from known data points on the curve.

An easy solution is to identify the two points on both sides of a change of sign and perform linear interpolation between them.

For better precision, as the derivatives are also available at these points, you can resort to inverse Hermite interpolation (interpolate $t$ as a cubic function of $\phi$).

Example with a much exaggerated step.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is the approach I ended up using. Sorry if the solution seemed trivial - first year student and completely new to the subject. Many thanks!

Comment: @albin: which one, I suggested two ?

Comment: Performing linear interpolation between both sides of a sign change.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. The figure below is shown as an addition to my previous comments.

[image]

The calculus was done with time increment dt= 0.00001 If more accuracy is needed one have to use a smaller dt.

For example with $dt= 0.00001$ the result found above for the period was $T= 7.59686$ . With $dt= 0.000001$ the result becomes $T= 7.596946$ which is closer to the value computed with WolframAlpha $T= 7.59696...$

Note : The initial angle 6*pi/7 is large. The usual formula to compute an approximate of the period are not convenient in this case because the too large deviation.

THEORY :

The analytical solving leads to
$$t(\phi)=\sqrt{\frac{2L}{g\,(B+1)}}\left(EllipticF\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\:\Bigg|\:\frac{2}{B+1} \right) - EllipticF\left(\frac{\phi_0}{2}\:\Bigg|\:\frac{2}{B+1} \right)\right)$$
$$B=\frac{L}{2g}(\phi'_0)^2-\cos(\phi_0)$$
$EllipticF$ is the function "Elliptic Integral of the first kind".

The maximum of $\phi$ (i.e.: amplitude) is :
$$\phi_{max}=\cos^{-1}(-B)$$
The period is :
$$T=4\:\:\sqrt{\frac{2L}{g\:(B+1)}}EllipticF\left(\frac{\phi_{max}}{2}\:\Bigg|\:\frac{2}{B+1} \right)$$
This formula comuped with WolframAlpha gives $\quad T= 7.59696...$